# Flutter: How to get value from ListWheel into TextField

Tags: flutter, textfield, mousewheel

I have a form with 3 text fields. I want to populate value into these fields by selecting an item in a ListWheelScrollView. Any suggestions on how to do that?
The selected field should get the value from the scrollwheel.

[image: ListWheel to the right]

ListWheel is populated with numbers from 100 to 200.

```
Widget _buildScrollWheel(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> list = _createSpeedTiles();
    return ListWheelScrollView(itemExtent: 30, children: list);
  }

  List<Widget> _createSpeedTiles() {
    List<Widget> list = [
      for (var i = 100; i < 200; i += 1)
        ListTile(
          title: Text('$i'),
        )
    ];

    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use inside ListWheelScrollView `onSelectItemChanged` to set value in your text field controller

```
 onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) => method()
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have found a solution. use onSelectedItemChanged property in ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate, which can listen the item index when scolling.**

```
ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                        onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {setState(() {seletedItem = index;});}, // I initialized selectedItem = 0 in `initState()`
                        itemExtent: 48,
                        squeeze: 1,
                        controller: fsc,
                        physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                        childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                          children: List<Widget>.generate(24, (index) {
                            if (index < 0 || index > 24) return null;
                            else if (index == 0) {
                              return Container(
                                child: Text('-', style:
                              seletedItem == index ?
                              CalendarTextStyle.selectedTimeStyle : CalendarTextStyle.timeStyle),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,);}
                            else {
                              return Container(
                                child: Text('$index', style:
                                seletedItem == index ?
                                CalendarTextStyle.selectedTimeStyle : CalendarTextStyle.timeStyle),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,);}
                          })
                        ),
                      ),
```